# Play Framework 2.5 - Reverse route to a variable in .java file from scala.html file

Tags: java, scala, playframework, twirl

I'm trying to refactor my Controllers & scala.html files to reduce the amount of parameters I'm passing from the Java Controller classes to the scala.html frontend files.

My plan is to refactor the code so that rather than passing the variables from the Java class to the scala.html, the scala.html files could reverse route back to the variables in the Java files.

E.g. rather than this:

```
@(someInteger: Int, someString: String, stringList: List[String], anotherInteger: Int)
```

Just have one or two variables:

```
@(someInteger: Int, someString: String)
```

And use reverse routes for the other variables where needed in the scala.html file like this:

```
@routes.SomeController.SomeMethod
```

Also, I'd like to add a scala comparison in the scala.html file to some of these variables such as:

```
@if(@routes.SomeController.SomeMethod == true){
    ...
}
```

The above works when passed in from the Java Controller classes as scala variables, but not (currently) when attempting to reverse route from the scala.html.

It's worth noting that the /GET route for controllers.SomeController.SomeMethod has been setup in the conf/routes file, I think it is a syntactical or logical issue.

Any help in accessing variables by reverse routing from the scala.html would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On your controllers you can use the map that is attached to the current request like this: `ctx().args.put("key", "value");`

On your views you can access the data that you placed on the map like this:
`@Controller.ctx().args.get("key")`.

Comment: That looks like a different syntax than I'm used to, are you sure that's the syntax to reverse route to variables (individual integer or string varables rather than maps) for play 2.5? Say I have a method in one of the controller classes that returns int, how would I reach that method from a scala.html file so it could be output on the view for example?

Comment: Yep, It is 2.5. [javadocs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.3/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html#args) That's the only way that I use to pass data from the controller to the view without using parameters. You can pass also via a `form` instance but I do not think that would be good on your case.

Comment: ok thank you I'll have a go at implementing that and let you know how I get on :)